# SQL Server : LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE MANAGER relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table `employee`:

[image: Actual Database Table]

`MANAGERID` is a self-referencing foreign key to `EMPLOYEEID`. I want to build a query which generates output of a 4th column called `DESIGNATION`.

The desired result looks like this:

[image: Logic Explanation for better understanding]

The logic is

1. Designation must be “Associate” when no other employee is reporting to this employee
2. Designation must be “Manager” when one or more employees are reporting to this employee
3. Designation must be “Head” when one or more managers are reporting to this employee

How to achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576). Also see [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). SO is not a free coding service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include your code as a [mre], and ask a specific question related to that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `case` with `not exists`:

```
select e.*,
       (case when managerid is null then 'head'
             when not exists (select 1 from employee e2 where e2.managerid = e.id)
             then 'associate'
             else 'manager'
        end) as designation
from employee e;
```

EDIT:

So, "head" seems to mean "manager's manager".  That can be accomplished as:

```
select e.*,
       (case when exists (select
                          from employee e2 join
                               employee e3
                               on e2.id = e3.managerid
                          where e2.managerid = e.id
                         )
             then 'head'
             when not exists (select 1 from employee e2 where e2.managerid = e.id)
             then 'associate'
             else 'manager'
        end) as designation
from employee e;
```

Comment: Thank you mate for the answers but the problem is the HEAD is not because of NULL in manager Id, If one are more manger is mapped to any employeeid , Then only it is HEAD, So here if you take LEE as example , He is HEAD  not because of NULL  Its cos BRUCE (Manager) is mapped to LEE., So i am facing hard to get that logic