# SQL join manager from same table onto a row with their employees

Tags: sql, sql-server

To start, here's a dummy table I've made to show the data I'm working with:

| employee | title | division | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boss Person | boss | o | bp@email |
| John Smith | supervisor | a | jos@email |
| Jane Smith | supervisor | b | jas@email |
| Leo Messi | employee | a | lm@email |
| Amanda Kessel | employee | a | ak@email |
| Derek Jeter | employee | b | dj@email |

I want to end up with the following info:

| employee | title | division | email | supervisor_name | supervisor_email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boss Person | boss | o | bp@email | NULL | NULL |
| John Smith | supervisor | a | jos@email | Boss Person | bp@email |
| Jane Smith | supervisor | b | jas@email | Boss Person | bp@email |
| Leo Messi | employee | a | lm@email | John Smith | jos@email |
| Amanda Kessel | employee | a | ak@email | John Smith | jos@email |
| Derek Jeter | employee | b | dj@email | Jane Smith | jas@email |

I've looked through and tried documentation at:

https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-self-join/

[SQL Server : LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE MANAGER relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073317/sql-server-left-join-employee-manager-relationship)

One of the big differences here is I don't have any employee or manager id column to work with.

If you're a supervisor for a division, ie John Smith is a supervisor in division a, then you manage all the employees in division a. Meanwhile, all the supervisors answer to the boss in division o, while the boss answers to no one.

Here is the best code I've tried so far:

```
select e.*, b.employee as supervisor, b.email as supervisor_email
from employees e, employees b
where b.division = e.division
and
b.title like '%supervisor%'
```

This got me close, it returned:

| employee | title | division | email | supervisor_name | supervisor_email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | supervisor | a | jos@email | John Smith | jos@email |
| Jane Smith | supervisor | b | jas@email | Jane Smith | jas@email |
| Leo Messi | employee | a | lm@email | John Smith | jos@email |
| Amanda Kessel | employee | a | ak@email | John Smith | jos@email |
| Derek Jeter | employee | b | dj@email | Jane Smith | jas@email |

So, it got the employee info right, but left out the Boss record and placed the supervisors as their own supervisor. I think I need some kind of case or if statement here, but I'm not sure.

Please let me know if this makes sense or if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: You *can't* perform a `LEFT JOIN` with that 1980's `JOIN` syntax; it was deprecated in SQL Server 2008 and removed in SQL Server 2012; it's time to join the 90's. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Also, get into the habit of using meaningful aliases. `e` for the `employee` and `m` for the manager `employee` would make *far* better choices for the aliases. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Ok sure, I'm still learning SQL so I didn't know that syntax was that old.
Thanks for the hyperlink, I'll read up on it.

Comment: If you're learning that syntax from material you're reading, @Seth , then it's time to find different material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a `LEFT JOIN` and work with two conditions:

- when division is the same and we're dealing with the relationship `employee < supervisor`
- when the relationship is `supervisor < boss`

Here's how I did it:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.employee,
       t2.email
FROM      tab t1
LEFT JOIN tab t2
       ON (t1.division = t2.division AND 
           t2.title = 'supervisor' AND 
           t1.title = 'employee') 
       OR (t2.title = 'boss' AND 
           t1.title = 'supervisor')
```

You'll find an SQL fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f81092bfb13e4c1b4b90da169f66ba40).

Comment: This worked - I didn't know you could do an ON statement with an OR clause like this. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, you can do further tricky/complex things by using operands different than `=` (e.g. you can do `t1.division > t2.division`). Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the current table (if columns are available), you can do the following (more or less the same as @lemon) :

```
UPDATE testing t1 JOIN testing t2 ON t2.`division`=t1.division OR t2.division="o" SET
t1.supervisor_name=t2.`employee`, t1.supervisor_email=t2.email
WHERE (CASE
WHEN t1.`title`="employee" THEN t2.title="supervisor"
WHEN t1.`title`="supervisor" THEN t2.title="boss"
END);
SELECT * FROM testing;
```